# How best to share an IDisposable object like SqlConnection with several methods in a class?

Tags: c#

Sometimes I have several methods all of which connect to SQL Server. This means that all methods contain local variables of IDisposable types like SqlConnection.

What is the best way to reuse one sqlconnection object? Would it be to pass it in as a reference and have it as a class-level variable? Also, if I use it throughout methods, does it need to be passed in by ref and should the class implement idisposable to dispose of the variable?

Thanks

Comment: In my opinion: just create it when and where needed - don't pass it around, don't have a single global static connection - just use as needed, open as late and close as early as possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When it comes to `SqlConnection`, [connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) will come into play, so in this case the answer is - don't share.

In general, unless a disposable object is *designed* for sharing, I wouldn't try to share it. There might be some cleanup required before it can be reused without consequence.

Comment: So stick to what I am doing - create an IDisposable object in one method, and in another? SqlConnection is a bad example, it can be any IDisposable object I am thinking of.

Comment: @dotnetdev - Yes, it is what I would do. For example - I wouldn't try to share a stream...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Oded - best practice for using `SqlConnection` is not sharing it.

If you need to share other `IDisposable` object between several methods than I would suggest you to implement `IDisposable` in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Oded's answer is concise and correct; you shouldn't share SqlConnections between using objects.

A more complete answer is that if you want to centralize control of SqlConnections, you should encapsulate them in a Repository object; a centralized database-access object. It has the dual advantage of putting the code that deals with SqlConnections in one place, and hiding that implementation detail from the rest of your code, so if you change to Oracle or MySql or SqLite, you don't have to refactor everything in your system. Do some research on Repository patterns; there should be an example of one or two that will "drop in" to a model that used to handle its own DB calls.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when you segregate stuff into several methods, a 'shared' connection (inside e.g. a class) may occur. For this, a pattern based on a closure works pretty well:

```
public void Do() {
  WithConnection(o => {
    o.Foo();
    o.Bar();
  });
}

private void WithConnection(Action<ThisClass> action) {
  try {
    con.Open();
    action(this);
  }
  finally {
    con.Dispose()
  }
}
```

I agree that in this special case, pooling may be your friend, but if you want to have a resource available throughout several methods (do several things that would usually fire an event, but you only want the event once, etc. etc.), a closure as shown can be your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't share an `SqlConnection` as Oded says, but I think it might be fine to share a `DataContext` between methods if you have one. The way I would do that is to let my own data access class implement `IDisposable`, and in the `Dispose` method for my data access class I would dispose my `DataContext`.